# Missing Custom Headers Using NGINX Ingress Controller on GCP

Tags: spring-boot, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I am creating an application based on Java 8 and Spring Boot using Docker and Kubernetes on Google Cloud Platform. The application is a RESTful API which has a HTTP header named as SIGNATURE. My point is that through ingress controller the SIGNATURE header isn't being passed.

#### Scenario

- Restfull APIs developed in Java and SpringBoot 1.5.8.
- Postman calling the Rest API sending the SIGNATURE header.
- API running in a Docker image at GCP executed by K8S.
- NGINX Ingress Controller is being used.
- Custom HTTP headers are required to send parameters for this API.

#### Problem

Throw "Missing request header SIGNATURE" exception while executing the api.

#### Question

How can I passing custom headers from client to the backend using NGINX Ingress Controller?

#### Artifacts

Springboot Controller Code Snippet:

```java
public ResponseEntity<TransactionDTO> get(
     @RequestHeader("SIGNATURE") String apiSignature,                    
     @RequestHeader("application/json") String contentType,                    
     @PathVariable Long id)
```

Ingress Controller YAML:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx   
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: api.domain.com.br
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /manager
        backend:
          serviceName: api-svc
          servicePort: 8086
```

Comment: I assume/suppose/hope you have already tried setting the headers from your application. Can you describe more the issue? Why are you getting only one header error? This means that the other ones are just fine or optional?

Comment: No, it is happening for all headers. The message is related to the SIGNATURE header  because I removed the other ones. I changed the description to consider postman invoking the web services.

Comment: @AlexandreBarbosadeSousa did you resolve this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Hi @oivoodoo, unfortunately the project stopped and I had given up to solve this issue. And you? Did you solve your issue?